# pygame, drawing an arc from point A to B in radius R

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to draw an arc from Point A to point B along the radius R. A semi-circle.

In `Player.__draw_fov()` you can see how I am currently drawing the arc. Which it draws, however, when I rotate the arc becomes messed up beyond 90 degrees. Now when I am doing the vector math to get the angle of fov vectors to the default vector (x, 0) it always returns a value `0 <= angle <= 180`. So it works for the top 180 to 0 degrees. But does not work for the bottom 180 to 360 degrees.

Now I tried various things including keeping track of the angle of player. Which starts at 90 (facing up)(0 faces right). When the player is facing below 0 or above 180 it shifts the degrees. But nothing seems to work.

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, distance, fov, color, start, pygame, screen):
        self.distance = distance
        self.fov = fov
        self.color = color
        self.pygame = pygame
        self.screen = screen
        self.left = False
        self.right = False

        self.angularSpeed = 5
        self.speed = 5

        self.angle = 90
        self.origin = start

        unit = 1 / numpy.linalg.norm(numpy.array([0, -10]))

        self.points = numpy.array([
            numpy.array([-3, 3]) + start,
            numpy.array([3, 3]) + start,
            numpy.array([0, -10]) + start,
            self.rotate([0, distance * unit * -10], self.fov / 2) + start,
            self.rotate([0, distance * unit * -10], -self.fov / 2) + start
        ])

    def update(self):
        if self.left: self._left()
        elif self.right: self._right()
        self._draw_body()
        self._draw_fov()

    def _draw_fov(self):
        P1 = self.points[3]
        P2 = self.points[4]
        self.pygame.draw.line(self.screen, self.color, self.origin, P1.tolist())
        self.pygame.draw.line(self.screen, self.color, self.origin, P2.tolist())

        O = numpy.array([10, 0])
        A1 = self.vector_angle(P1-self.origin, O)
        A2 = self.vector_angle(P2-self.origin, O)

        if self.angle >= 135: A2 = -A2
        if self.angle >= 225: A1 = -A1
        if self.angle <=  45: A1 = -A1
        if self.angle >= 315: A2 = -A2

        O_corner = self.origin - numpy.array([self.distance, self.distance])

        if (135 <= self.angle < 225) or
           (0 <= self.angle <= 45) or
           (315 <= self.angle < 360):
            self.pygame.draw.arc(self.screen, self.color, (O_corner, (self.distance * 2, self.distance * 2)), math.radians(A1), math.radians(A2))
        else:
            self.pygame.draw.arc(self.screen, self.color, (O_corner, (self.distance * 2, self.distance * 2)), math.radians(A2 - 90), math.radians(A1 + 90))

    def vector_angle(self, A, B):
        dot = A[0] * B[0] + A[1] * B[1]
        norm = numpy.linalg.norm(A) * numpy.linalg.norm(B)

        return math.degrees(math.acos(dot/norm))

    def _left(self):
        self.angle = (self.angle + self.angularSpeed) % 360
        for point in range(self.points.shape[0]):
            self.points[point] = self.rotate(self.points[point], -self.angularSpeed, self.origin)
        self.directionVector = self.rotate(self.directionVector, -self.angularSpeed)

    def _right(self):
        self.angle = (self.angle - self.angularSpeed) % 360
        for point in range(self.points.shape[0]):
            self.points[point] = self.rotate(self.points[point], self.angularSpeed, self.origin)
        self.directionVector = self.rotate(self.directionVector, self.angularSpeed)
```

**EDIT**
Changed and formatted to be more idiomatic (ternary comparisons and % modulus, which works with negatives). The comparisons < 0 and >= 360 are no longer necessary.

**EDIT**

I improved the algorithm to draw the arc better as it turns, it seems to be correct as you turn. <s>However, over time the arc starts to draw incorrectly as the player turns constantly. This seems to be an accumulative issue I cannot see.</s> The cumulative issue is inside _right(), it occurs where 360 - self.angle, this is fixed with 360 + self.angle

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should try radians i/o degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By keeping an angle variable to denote the direction the player is facing and using that to adapt the vector angle calculated between the two FOV vectors and the origin vector ([10, 0]) I was able to adapt the angles so it always drew the arc correctly.

Each of these angles modify  the angles of the FOV vectors based on whether or not the self.angle is beyond certain 45 degree points. Basically this informs when the FOV is in the lower half of the circle. Since using vectors to get the angle only works between 0 and 180 degrees, it does not consider the angles above 180 as these are just negative values between 0 and -180 which vectors do not care about.

These angles only work for a fov of 90 degrees. To compensate for any fov I modified them as follows:

```
if self.angle >= 180-self.fov/2: A2 = -A2
if self.angle >= 180+self.fov/2: A1 = -A1
if self.angle <=  self.fov/2: A1 = -A1
if self.angle >= 360-self.fov/2: A2 = -A2

# if self.angle >= 135: A2 = -A2 # 90 + 45
# if self.angle >= 225: A1 = -A1 # 180 + 45
# if self.angle <=  45: A1 = -A1 # 45
# if self.angle >= 315: A2 = -A2 # 270 + 45

O_corner = self.origin - numpy.array([self.distance, self.distance])

if (self.angle >= 135 and self.angle < 225) or (self.angle <= 45 and self.angle >= 0) or (self.angle >= 315 and self.angle < 360):
self.pygame.draw.arc(self.screen, self.color, (O_corner, (self.distance*2, self.distance*2)), math.radians(A1), math.radians(A2))
else:
    self.pygame.draw.arc(self.screen, self.color, (O_corner, (self.distance*2, self.distance*2)), math.radians(A2-90), math.radians(A1+90))
```

The code in my question has been updated and